# optimize MySQL query with FULL TEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking too much time if keywords are more than one (like: "photo frame"). The table is in InnoDB engine. I have following indexes in the table (Indexname  type  columns):

1. fldForSearch        FULLTEXT        fldForSearch
2. fldProductsOffered  FULLTEXT        fldProductsOffered
3. fldCompanyProfile   FULLTEXT        fldCompanyProfile
4. profile_product     FULLTEXT      fldCompanyProfile,fldProductsOffered
5. product_brand       FULLTEXT        fldProductsOffered,fldCompanyBrand
6. profile_products_brand FULLTEXT fldCompanyProfile,fldProductsOffered,fldCompanyBrand
7. fldCompanyBrand FULLTEXT         fldCompanyBrand
8. fldForProductSearch FULLTEXT    fldForProductSearch
9. cp_cb_po_ps    FULLTEXT fldCompanyProfile
10. fs_cb  FULLTEXT    fldForSearch,fldCompanyBrand
11. fs_cb_ps   FULLTEXT    fldForSearch,fldCompanyBrand,fldForProductSearch

Here is the query:

```
SELECT count( S.fldProfileId ) total, group_concat( DISTINCT (
U.fldCountry
)
SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS allCountryIds,
MATCH (
S.fldForSearch, S.fldCompanyBrand
)
AGAINST (
'"photo frames"'
) AS rank1, (

MATCH (
S.fldForSearch, S.fldCompanyBrand
)
AGAINST (
'photo photos'
)
AND MATCH (
S.fldForSearch, S.fldCompanyBrand
)
AGAINST (
'frame frames'
)
) AS rank2,
MATCH (
S.fldForProductSearch
)
AGAINST (
'"photo frames"'
) AS rank3, (

MATCH (
S.fldForProductSearch
)
AGAINST (
'photo photos'
)
AND MATCH (
S.fldForProductSearch
)
AGAINST (
'frame frames'
)
) AS rank4
FROM tblUserMaster U, tblSupplierProfileMaster AS S
WHERE S.fldHideSource = 'N'
AND S.fldUserId = U.fldUserId
AND U.fldUserStatus = 'Y'
AND S.fldProfileStatus = 'A'
AND MATCH (
S.fldForSearch, S.fldCompanyBrand, S.fldForProductSearch
)
AGAINST (
' photo photos frame frames'
)
```

I have index combinations for all the columns present in FULLTEXT search.
The query takes time for the first time, but next time it runs quickly.

I recreated all the indexes but no effect. Even `Optimize Table` did not helped.

**Update:** The result of the above query is:

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| total | allCountryIds      | rank1              | rank2 | rank3       | rank4 |
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|  3390 | 222, 104, 223, ... | 14.645795822143555 |     1 | 60246.34375 |     1 |
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblSupplierProfileMaster` (
 `fldProfileId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fldUserId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `fldProductsOffered` text NOT NULL,
 `fldCompanyProfile` text NOT NULL,
 `fldCompanyBrand` text NOT NULL,
 `fldForSearch` text NOT NULL,
 `fldForProductSearch` longtext NOT NULL,
 `fldDateOfCreation` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `fldLastModifyDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `fldProfileStatus` enum('A','P','D') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
 PRIMARY KEY (`fldProfileId`),
 UNIQUE KEY `fldUserId` (`fldUserId`),
 UNIQUE KEY `fldProfileStatus` (`fldProfileStatus`,`fldHideSource`,`fldUserId`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fldForSearch` (`fldForSearch`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fldProductsOffered` (`fldProductsOffered`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fldCompanyProfile` (`fldCompanyProfile`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `profile_product` (`fldCompanyProfile`,`fldProductsOffered`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `product_brand` (`fldProductsOffered`,`fldCompanyBrand`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `profile_products_brand` (`fldCompanyProfile`,`fldProductsOffered`,`fldCompanyBrand`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fldCompanyBrand` (`fldCompanyBrand`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fldForProductSearch` (`fldForProductSearch`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `cp_cb_po_ps` (`fldCompanyProfile`,`fldCompanyBrand`,`fldProductsOffered`,`fldForProductSearch`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fs_cb` (`fldForSearch`,`fldCompanyBrand`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fs_cb_ps` (`fldForSearch`,`fldCompanyBrand`,`fldForProductSearch`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=304194 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='store the profile of suppliers'
```

**Update 2:** Explain query result:

```
+------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys                            | key      | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | S     | fulltext | fldUserId,fldProfileStatus,DEV1,fs_cb_ps | fs_cb_ps | 0       |                       |    1 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | U     | eq_ref   | PRIMARY,fldMemberId,fldUserStatus        | PRIMARY  | 4       | wdeals_uk.S.fldUserId |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Pls show us the result of the explain and pls also include the output of the show create table to display all indices.

Comment: @Shadow, question updated

Comment: We need the output of the **explain**, not the select. Run `explain select <the rest of your query>` and pls paste the results into the question.

Comment: question updated.

Comment: "but next time it runs quickly" -->  That's the Query cache.